# Can I run a sql query in another file?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

I am busy with a school project to learn MVC. But I know very little of php.
I have an dbconnection file and it looks like this

```
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "filmopdrachtdb";

$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection Failed: " . $conn->connet_error);
}

echo "Connected SuccessFully";
```

I have a login page that looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Login</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <form action="../Controllers/UserController.php" method="post">
        Gebruikersnaam <input type="text" name="naam">
        Wachtwoord <input type="password" name="wachtwoord">
        <input type="submit" value="Login">
    </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

And I have an User Controller that looks like this:

```
<?php
include_once ("../Includes/DbConnection.php");
include_once ("../Models/User.php");

$gebruiker = new User();
$naam = $gebruiker->setGebruikersnaam($_POST["naam"]);
$wachtwoord = $gebruiker->setWachtwoord($_POST["wachtwoord"]);

$stmt = "SELECT gebruikersnaam, wachtwoord FROM klanten";


var_dump($stmt);
```

How do I run the $stmt query. I don't understand what I have to do

```
$stmt = "SELECT gebruikersnaam, wachtwoord FROM klanten";
```

EDIT: I want the query `$stmt` to run in the UserController. Not in the DbConnection file.

Comment: You can find details about your request in the official documentation, check this link : https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.statements.php

Comment: _Tip:_ I would recommend using [PDO](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) instead of mysqli. PDO gives you a more verbose API. making it easier to work with.

Answer (score 1):

If you use stm, you can execute with that code:

```
$stmt=$conn->prepare("SELECT gebruikersnaam, wachtwoord FROM klanten WHERE user=?");
$stmt->bind_param('s',$naam);
$stmt->execute();
```

OR

```
$conn->query($stmt);
```

Comment: The first one would throw an error since `$stmt` is a string and not a statement.

Comment: Yes but we dont know if he want use statement or not. i will correct

Answer (score 0):

In your `DbConnection.php` file you have a `$conn` variable which contains your connection to the database. From that variable you can execute your queries on the database.

From the [mysqli PHP documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php), modified to work with your code:

```
$results = $conn->query($stmt);
```

Please note that this method should not be used with a dynamically generated query string:

```
//BAD practice, leads to SQL injection
$results = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE myColumn = $search LIMIT 10");
```

For dynamically generated queries use [prepared queries](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php).

I could also suggest to use [PDO](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) which is a more versatile database interaction libraray in PHP, which you will probably not be able to do for that code as it is for school, but for your own projects :)

Comment: But I want to use the  ```$conn``` variable in the UserController not in the connection file. Can I just use it like your first line of code or do I need to do something else

Comment: Use function include or require_once for call controller to your page.

Comment: Your user controller already includes your `DbConnection.php` file :) 
`include_once ("../Includes/DbConnection.php");`